# Adding slideUp / slideDown to hover function

Tags: jquery, hover, slidedown, slideup

I have been helped with the code to hover over an image and for another image to appear over the original.

```
$('.hoverpic').hover(function () {
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg','_hover.jpg'));
}, function () {
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('_hover.jpg','.jpg'));
});
```

It works well but I would like the second image to slideUp on hover and then slideDown when leaving. I'm very new to this and try as I might cannot get it to work.  Very simplified help would be appreciated

Comment: I think this is going to be more complex. I don't think you can simply add an animation, because you only have one image element. The simplest solution might be to put two images in a div with `overflow:hidden`, have the hover image outside the visible area of the div, and use `animate` to slide it into view on hover.

Comment: Thanks for looking @jason Examples can be seen at [link](http://castonwebdesigns.co.uk/portfolio.asp) where there are two images for each case.  If you could lay down some example code it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method assumes the image(s) are the same width and height and have a fixed width/height.

You declare both images (the normal and the hover) in the html to start with in a 'containing' div, giving this container the same width and height as the images (in my example I've used 300px by 200px). The hover image is hidden outside of the frame at first (using absolute positioning on the images and `overflow: hidden` on the container div with CSS) but it slides in on hover.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2JSxK/7/

Just replace the HTML there with:

```
<div id="image-container">
    <img class="pic" src="YOURIMAGENAME.jpg" />
    <img class="hoverpic" src="YOURIMAGENAME_hover.jpg" />
</div>
```

And the CSS with the width and heights of your image:

```
#image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px; /* put your image width in pixels here */
    height: 200px; /* put your image height in pixels here */
    overflow: hidden;
    }

#image-container img.pic {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    }

#image-container img.hoverpic {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px; /* put your image height in pixels here */
    left: 0;
    }
```

The same in the jQuery, just replace `200` twice with your image height in pixels:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pic').hover( 
        function () {
            $('.hoverpic').animate({ "top": "-=200px" }, "slow" );
        },
        function () {
            $('.hoverpic').animate({ "top": "+=200px" }, "slow" );
        }
     );
 });
```

You can also change the speed above `"slow"` to `"fast"` or a number in milliseconds, eg. `1000` would be a second. Depends how fast you want the sliding to happen obviously!

**Corrected:** Hover effect now associated with the container rather than the individual image, so that hover image doesn't disappear when you move your mouse.

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2JSxK/16/

New jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#image-container').hover( 
        function () {
            $('.hoverpic').animate({ "top": "-=200px" }, "slow" );
        },
        function () {
            $('.hoverpic').animate({ "top": "+=200px" }, "slow" );
        }
     );
 });
```

**Edited:** To account for more than one of this animation happening on a page, I changed how I structured/wrote things slightly (see below comments).

Latest demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2JSxK/17/

Comment: This is the same/similar method as Jason P mentions in his comment, I wrote it before I saw his comment!

Comment: Sarah, this is very simply laid out and exactly the kind of information I need at my stage of trying to understand jQuery.  At present though the hoverpic in your example continues to slide up and down and I want it to stay in place while the mouse is hovering over the image so enabling the visitor to read the content.  What is the tweak necessary to make that happen please?

Comment: I think I have fixed this now. The hover animation is now associated with the container rather than the normal image state. http://jsfiddle.net/2JSxK/16/

Comment: Sarah that is fabulous.  Thank you very much for a perfect result.  I am avidly reading jQuery tuition stuff in order to improve and increase my knowldge.

Comment: This popped into my head again today and I realised I probably could have written this better to account for having more than one instance of this on a page. Thought it might help you or someone else. The HTML uses `image-container` as a class rather than an id and the jQuery only targets the pictures inside the current container. The way I'd written it before this wouldn't have worked if it happened more than once on a page. See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2JSxK/17/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need slideToggle for this:
http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

```
<div id="container">
<img id="img1" src="http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120626230828/watchdogs/images/6/6c/IE-icon.png" alt="" />
<img id="img2" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_%282011%29.png" alt="" style="display:none"/>
</div>

$('#container').hover(function() {
    $('#img1').slideToggle(500, 'linear');
    $('#img2').slideToggle(500, 'linear');
});
```

Check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/suneeel/SRNJb/1/

Comment: Sunil, thank you for taking the time to look at this for me but your solution doesn't quite achieve the effect I was looking for which is to have the second image slide up over the first image and stay in place while the mouse is hovering thereby enabling the visitor to read the content of the second image.  The second image then slides down when the mouse moves away.